# Receiving empty emails in validated form

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm receiving alot of empty mails from my contact form. Because it has validation on it i dont know how this is possible.

This is my form (only gave one row  to give an indication):

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
 <div class="messages"></div>

                    <div class="controls">
                         <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Aanhef *</label>
                                <div class="label-group">
                                    <label class="radio-inline"><input class="radio" type="radio" required="required" value="Dhr." name="titel">Dhr.</label>                                    
                                    <label class="radio-inline"><input class="radio" type="radio" required="required" value="Mevr." name="titel">Mevr.</label>                                    
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>

                      <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_email">E-mail adres *</label>
                                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([\.a-zA-Z0-9_-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$" placeholder="Uw e-mailadres *" required="required" data-error="Uw e-mailadres (zonder spaties!)">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
```

This is my validation (contact.php):

```
<?php


// configure
$from = 'myemail'; 
$sendTo = 'myemail';

$senderNaam = $_POST['naam'];
$senderEmail = $_POST['email'];

$subject = 'Contact';
$okMessage = '<p>Send succesfully!</p>';
$errorMessage = '<p>Error!</p>';

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ". $from. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $senderNaam." <".$senderEmail.">\r\n";

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "New message\n=============================\n";

    $emailText = "<table>
            <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Naam:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['titel']." ".$_POST['naam']."</td></tr>
            <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Bedrijfsnaam:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['bedrijfsnaam']."</td></tr>
            <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Adres:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['straat']." ".$_POST['huisnummer']." ".$_POST['toevoeging']."</td></tr>
            <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Postcode:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['postcode']." ".$_POST['letters']."</td></tr>
            <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Woonplaats:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['woonplaats']."</td></tr>
            <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Telefoonnummer:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['kengetal']." ".$_POST['telefoon']."</td></tr>
            <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>E-mailadres:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>
            <tr><td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Bericht:</td><td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".$_POST['bericht']."</td></tr>
            </table>";

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $headers);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}

?>
```

From a post here on SO someone said, and i quote: "Have you considered that the action url may be directly accesed from the browser without any kind of POST data?. That would make all the "fields" empty."

This could be the problem, but i dont know how to solve this. Does someone has an idea, because my mailbox is running full LOL.

EDIT 1 : Alright i tried this:

```
// add all your other fields here
if (!isset($_POST['naam']) || !isset($_POST['email'])) {
mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $headers);
}
$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
```

But no result, still can open contact.php in my browser which says "Form send succesfully" :(.

Comment: Anyone could help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't performing any kind of server-side validation in your PHP. So yes, just pointing my browser to www.yoursite.com/contact.php would allow me to continue sending you empty emails.

Additionally, the `mail` function does not throw Exceptions. So there's no point in trying to wrap it in a `try`/`catch` block here. You should be checking the return value of that function to know that it failed.

You can perform some basic validation on user-supplied input from `$_POST` like this...

```
// add all your other fields here
if (!isset($_POST['naam']) || !isset($_POST['email'])) {
    /* user did not supply there name/email don't send mail */
}


// you may also want to do additional validation like required input length or valid email
if (strlen($_POST['somefield']) < $requiredLength) {
    /* input too short */
}
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    /* not a valid email address */
}
```

Also, you shouldn't blindly inject user-supplied input into your email headers. If the user provides a value with CRLF characters, for example, they can inject headers into your email. You should strip all CRLF characters from `$senderNaam` and `$senderEmail` before adding to your email header.

And don't forget that since you're using HTML you are also subject to HTML injection from user input just like in a browser. Make sure to use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on output.

```
"<tr>" .
    "<td style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background: #eee;'>Naam:</td>" .
    "<td style='padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>".
        htmlspecialchars($_POST['titel']) ." ". htmlspecialchars($_POST['naam']) .
    "</td>" .
"</tr>"
```

You should also note that validation alone still won't prevent anyone from spamming your contact form. It's trivial to just write a script that sends thousands of requests to this PHP script.

Try adding something like [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) to your form to prevent this.

Comment: Wow thanks! Although this goes quite above my head, i will give it a try. I'm also using "input pattern" in some fields, does that change anything? O i forgot to ask, you mean with "removing your CRLF characters", remove all the \r\n in my $headers? What if i place the php code into my html, does that make things easier? It has to be as simple as possible because my php knowledge isnt that well actually :(

Comment: Yes, `\r\n` is **Carriage Return** and **Line Feed** character.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i haven't been able to fix my problem yet. If you have an easier solution please let me know, in the meantime i will struggle on.

Comment: Where should i add this?         // add all your other fields here
if (!isset($_POST['naam']) || !isset($_POST['email'])) {
    /* user did not supply there name/email don't send mail */
}